# How could this loop print the correct statement then evaluate it incorrectly?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I wrote this  small function that will take and integer *k*, and return the product:

**2(0)+1 <sup>.</sup> 2(1)+1 <sup>.</sup> 2(2)+1 <sup>.</sup> ... 2n+1 || for n=0,n<(k/2)-1**
if  *k* is even, (or 0, I'm not sure if technically zero is an even number) And 0 if k is odd.

This was part of a larger project but I was able to isolate the problem to this function, and I pulled it out to try and figure out what was going on. Here is my function.

```
double Product_2np1(int k)
 {
    int prod = 1;
    if(k % 2 == 0)
      {
       for(int n = 0; n <(k/2);n++){
       prod = prod * ((2*n)+ 1);
      }
      return prod;
    }else return 0;
 }


int main(){
    for(int i=0; i<5;i++)
       {
         std::cout <<"k= " << i<< "==>" << Product_2np1(i) << std::endl;
       }
return 0; 
}
```

The output:

- k= 0 ==> 2.64619e-260
- k= 1 ==> 0
- k= 2 ==> 2.64619e-260
- k= 3 ==> 0
- k= 4 ==> 2.64619e-260
- k= 5 ==> 0

Now this was nonsense to me, so I went back into the function and threw in some prints to see what was going on. Changing `Product_2np1` to this:

```
double Product_2np1(int k)
 {
    int prod = 1;
    if(k % 2 == 0)
      {
       for(int n = 0; n <(k/2);n++){
       std::cout << "(2*" << n << ")+ 1)" <<std:endl;
      }
      return 1;
    }else return 0;
 }
```

and In main I only had the k=4 case evaluate:

```
int main(){
     Product_2np1(4);
return 0; 
}
```

This gave me the output:

- 2(0)+1
- 2(1)+1

Using my handy-dandy TI-86 I punched this in to make sure I wasn't loosing it and I get

- 2(0)+1 = 0+1 =1
- 2(1)+1 = 2+1 =3

and multiplying those together should give me 3, not 2.64619e-260.

So I have to ask you folks what could possibly be going on here?

Comment: http://ideone.com/OiSeXL <- your code works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your datatype - your function `double Product_2np1(int k)` returns `double` while `prod` is an `int`. I do not know which compiler you are using (maybe Turbo C) - but you should have got at least a warning regarding this. Normally the type conversion happens from smaller to larger - hence is think the result here i undefined - see this [Sample on Ideone](http://ideone.com/KEXXWh). The problem is that we are trying a forced conversion from `int` to `double` which is the problem.

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    printf("%lf", 2);
    printf("\n%lf", 2.0);
    return 0; 
}
```

Output:

```
Success time: 0 memory: 3340 signal:0
0.000000
2.000000
```

From the C standard (1999):
**6.3.1.4 Real floating and integer**

> 1 When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer
>   type other than _Bool, the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the
>   value is truncated toward zero). If the value of the integral part
>   cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undefined.

From the C++ standard (2003):

> **4.9 Floating-integral conversions [conv.fpint]**   1 An rvalue of a floating point type can be converted to an rvalue of an integer type.
>   The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part is discarded.
>   The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented
>   in the destination type. [Note: If the destination type is bool, see
>   4.12. ]

Comment: Why would that warn, and why would that result in a result that's off by ~260 orders of magnitude for a small values?

Comment: I changed that and the entire project is working properly, I feel a little silly now.  Isn't that something that should cause an error or warning when I compile?

Comment: But, isn't prod implicitly converted to double before it's returned? It shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Ajay: while that correction is ok, that shouldn't have been an issue at all. Your code works as you posted it (except for an error in the cout that would have caused a hard compile error).

Comment: @matt I am even more confused now. The error in cout was a typo I made when I posted the question, but after seeing your comment I moved the original project from my laptop to our cluster and compiled there, and it ran with no problems. The same thing for the segment I pulled out that is the subject of my question.

Comment: I also did think of what @Brainstorm mentioned as well, after seeing this answer, but I changed it and it worked so I figured I was mistaken

Comment: @All - Please see my edits. I have posted an example - its causing UB which is quiet clear.

Comment: Using printf is not the same as cout. Printf is a variadic c function and relies on type info from the format string. Cout uses operator overloading and the types are checked statically at compile time.

Comment: @al-Acme I appreciate the extra details. Since you brought it up: I compiled using gcc (version 4.9.2) I installed the compiler using homebrew, and I compiled using the command `gcc test.cc -o test`

Comment: `Cout uses operator overloading and the types are checked statically at compile time.` Precisely why `cout` behaves decently but `printf` does not - Ajay's example matches the `printf` situation.